# Update Values within Push firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase data Structure.
[image]

Now what basically I want to do is, first there is the **Id:"cbn"**. I have pushed the Location with **push().setValue(gpsData).** Now based on this **id = "cbn"**, I want to add new Latitude and Longitude in the **Location child** exactly like shown in the figure above by using **"push().** Till now my code is:

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    if (busExists) {
                    // busId = "cbn"
                    mDatabase.child(busId).child("Location").push().setValue(gpsData);


                }
```

I know I cannot reference **busId** as child but how can I access that particular node and push my new data to it.

Any Help?

For new question:

```
   public class Users {
    private String bus_id;
    private HashMap<String, String> coord = new HashMap<>();

    public Users() {

    }

    public String getBus_id() {
        return bus_id;
    }

    public void setBus_id(String bus_id) {
        this.bus_id = bus_id;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(HashMap<String, String> coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }
}
```

I implemented it this way:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Users bus = new Users();
                    bus.setBus_id(ds.getValue(Users.class).getBus_id());

                    Log.e("bus id: ", bus.getBus_id()+""); // I got NULL

                    busList.add(bus.getBus_id());

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fire a query to get the push ID of `cbn` and then add the location from there:

```
Query query = ref.child("Users").orderByChild("Id").equalTo("cbn");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot user: snapshot.getChildren()) {
      user.getRef().child("Location").push().setValue(...);
```

The loop in `onDataChange()` is needed, since there may be multiple child nodes matching the query. If there can only be one child with a specific `Id`, consider storing the users under that Id.

```
Users
  cbd
    Locations:...
```

With this structure you can add a new location without first querying:

```
ref.child("Users/cbn/Location").push().setValue(...);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But again, I have another little problem. I've edited the code for you (also the diagram). Now what I want is to read all the data(ID, location) for all those individual nodes i.e for each id 'cbn' , 'uoohj' and so on. For that, I created a Users class and it records 'id' and 'coord' hashmap which stores latitude and longitude. Also I have mentioned  the method I followed in above code. But it didn't worked. Can you please give some insights on how to do it? Thanks.